What is the electric field at the center axis of a solenoid?
If I have an ideal and really long solenoid, with a time-varying currying running through it, thus creating a time-varying magnetic field inside it, what will be the electric field on the region inside it? I'm not referring to the electric field inside the wire forming the coil, but rather to the field inside the cyllindrical region enclosed by the coil.

Did you apply Faraday’s law of induction?

What have you tried?

Knowing $\vec{B}(\vec{r},t)$, start with Faraday's law
$$\nabla\times \vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}, $$
now use $\nabla \times\nabla \times\vec{E}=\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec{E})-\nabla^2\vec{E} =-\nabla^2 \vec{E}$ knowing that $\rho=0$. Then
$$\nabla^2\vec{E}=\frac{\partial(\nabla \times \vec{B})}{\partial t}. $$
This is a Poisson equation, an equation that has a well-known solution. You may define $\vec{\zeta}_B=-\partial(\nabla \times \vec{B})/\partial t $ for simplicity. The solution is
$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\iiint_{V'}\frac{\vec{\zeta}_B(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}dV', $$
where $\vec{r}$ refers to the field points and $\vec{r}'$ refers to the source points. For the specific case of a solenoid, the magnetic field inside the inner space is roughly uniform. A uniform magnetic field has zero curl and therefore does not contribute to the electric field. The contributions to the electric field come from the time-varying outer magnetic field that has non-zero curl.
